# Why do I need to include part of my namespace despite having a 'using' declaration?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I have one project in my solution geared towards providing some core functionality. It's namespace is `MyCompanyName.ProductName.FunctionSet`. At this time, this project includes two classes; `customer.cs` and `core.cs`. The core class is static and contains a static method EntryPoint().

I have a console app in the solution. Its namespace is `MyCompanyName.ProductName.TaskMan`. I created a reference to the core project above and added a using directive for the namespace.

One of the lines in `Main()` is `Core.EntryPoint();` . Note, it does not include any part of the namespace. The code was running fine.

Now, in order to resolve an error (Cannot resolve symbol 'EntryPoint') I needed to change the line to `FunctionSet.Core.EntryPoint();` . I needed to add the last part of the namespace.

Why did I need to add that portion of the namespace? Any ideas why it suddenly stopped working? Is there anything I can do to omit the namespace portion? It's not a big deal if I'm stuck with this but I do want to know the how and why.

Comment: Could you include your `using` statements?

Comment: I assume it is because that it conflicts with a different class like Core. Try giving an alias to your reference and see if that works: using fs = MyCompanyName.ProductName.FunctionSet; and then accessing it via fs.Core etc.

Comment: My guess is that you added a refernce to another namespace that also contains a class called Core. (Possibly a .Net Framework class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I've preserved the bulky bit below, but I'm now not sure it's relevant.

I suspect that one of these is true:

- Your namespaces aren't quite what you think they are (in particular for Core)
- You don't have the using directive you think you do

If you could post a short but complete program (just the two classes should be enough, and just the namespace, using directives, class declaration and methods - no need for any business logic) it should be easy enough to sort out.

---

Namespaces aren't resolved relative to `using` directives, although they *are* resolved relative to the current namespace. For example:

```
namespace Outer.Inner
{
    class Foo
    {
        public static void Bar() {}
    }
}

namespace Outer.OtherInner
{
    class Test1        
    {
        static void Method()
        {
            // Resolved to Outer.Inner.Foo.Bar()
            Inner.Foo.Bar();
        }
    }
}

namespace OtherOuter
{
    using Outer;

    class Test2
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // This is invalid
            Inner.Foo.Bar();
        }
    }
}
```

For the full gory details, look at section 3.8 of the C# specification.

Comment: The namespace for Core.cs was xxx.xxx.Core. Somewhere along the way we renamed some stuff. I'm not sure why I didn't pick that up sooner. After renaming Core.cs to Test.cs, the problem became apparent. Thanks!

Comment: @SpecialAgent_W436: The Core class was in a Core namespace? That's definitely a bad idea - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/03/09/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one.aspx and the subsequent parts.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the function in a using statement at the beginning of the file?

```
using FunctionSet.Core.EntryPoint
EntryPoint();
```